# What would the items look like if we put them on a length scale?

Tags: multiscale-modeling

The following table is taken from page#434 of the book *Schlick, Tamar. Molecular modeling and simulation: an interdisciplinary guide. Vol. 2. New York: Springer, 2010.*

[image]

- **What would the same items look like if we put them on a length scale?**

Comment: Length scale relative to what? I assume you want to compare it to the wavelength of light?

Comment: @Szgoger I think the OP is after length scales as in nanometer, etc. the green and yellow sections won't have an answer, just an adhoc range. The red ones (specific cases) can be typed into google i.e., a carbon-carbon bond is typically 1.54 angstroms...

Comment: @B.Kelly That's one possibility, but the table lists motions, and I find it hard to justify that they are after the size of the object that makes this motion. Maybe they are looking for the average displacement?

Comment: @Szgoger I would agree, it is likely displacement

Comment: No answer to any of these comments?